# Center an absolute positioned div with max-width

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm pretty new to web design and need a little help/suggestions with even the most simple things until i get used to it. Now to my problem:

I have an absolute positioned div (that actually is going to become my header), that overlays a gallery. Now i want this to be centered horizontally and also be responsive (have a max-width). Since I'm not used to css yet, i get some weird behaviour.

```
header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  /*put padding or margin here*/

  font-size: 0px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

As far as i understand: I'm inheriting the width of the parent. But now when I add a margin or padding to the left and right the width obviously exceeds the width of the parent (meaning that the cotnent of the header overflows on the right and i get a vertical scrollbar). What am I supposed to do, to get the behaviour I want?

Thanks in advance,

Yggdrasill

Comment: center things like this, its easier. https://jsfiddle.net/4fo7kty9/

Comment: This seems to work, but has actually nothing to do with my approach. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simpliest way is to wrap header within **the** absolute container:

```css
div {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  }
header {
  max-width:1000px;
  margin:auto;
  background:tomato;
  }
```

```html
<div><header>header, run me in full page mode</header></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. exactly what i looked for.